# Why is ADB not working on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, android

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and adb is excutable but when I use the commands in the terminal I get this:

> adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

How do I get ADB to work?

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: Thanks man it worked u should make it an answer so i can accept it that way it makes it look answered

Comment: great! answer added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the 32-bit libraries: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`